# Non-standard Bearer token and Blazor Webassembly authorization

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

My client-side Blazor is receiving a token in a header, let's call it `MyCustomJWTBearer` and based on that it needs to do two things:

1. Show and hide elements based on the claims within the supplied
   `MyCustomJWTBearer`
2. Enable the `HttpClient` to pass the same `MyCustomJWTBearer` to the server-side APIs

The client-side doesn't manage the authorization or authentication and this is managed by a proxy, so the only concern here is to extract `MyCustomJWTBearer` and the claims within it, no need to validate them or to check the issuer.

**N.B.** I am not interested in a full Blazor security as the product is protected at the API-level.

My custom `CustomAuthenticationStateProvider` does not have access to the HTTP Header so I cannot access `MyCustomJWTBearer`. Also, I don't want the full OIDC process as I am only interested in extracting the header and the claim. **What do I need to do to access the header in my `CustomAuthenticationStateProvider` and if this is not the solution then could you point me in the right direction?**

I have also followed this article https://chrissainty.com/securing-your-blazor-apps-authentication-with-clientside-blazor-using-webapi-aspnet-core-identity/ which shows how to set the HttpClient auth header but it is assuming the app is handling the auth.

Comment: So what do you get when you use the standard AuthenticationStateProvider  in a page and call `AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()`?  A `null` user?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis it does whatever I implemented in the `public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()` but that is not helping as I cannot have access to `HttpContext` in this method

Comment: Not sure I understand your answer.  My question was "What do your get when you run the out-of-the-box `AuthenticationStateProvider`".  The out-of-the-box implementation  reads information from the security headers.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis the `AuthenticationStateProvider` is abstract and it has to be inherited and the implementations of `GetAuthenticationStateAsync()` should be written, there is no default implementation `public abstract Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync();` I am under the impression that you should inherit it and use the child version.